# My sed from a bash script terminates when ran with "unterminated address regex"

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting, sed

Having some issues with a bash script I'm assembling.

`$2` is a string similar to "line_old" that's supplied during launch.  The sed dies with

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unterminated address regex
```

Here is my code snippet:

```bash
redisconfig ()
{
    CMD="ssh -q -t -i $HOME/.ssh/amazon-key.pem ubuntu@10.20.10.1"

    line_old="ENV['REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://redis:X9g532mq21yY4@ip-10-112-143-152.us-west-2.compute.internal:6379'"

    line_new="ENV['REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://redis:X9gKQasdg2yY4@$2:6379'"

    updateconfig="$($CMD sed "/$line_old/c\$line_new/" /home/ubuntu/config/testing.rb)"

    results="$($CMD grep 'REDIS_URL' /home/ubuntu/config/testing.rb)"

    echo $updateconfig

    echo $results    
}
```

Any idea what could be going on with me sed?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: The slashes in `$line_old` may be getting interpreted as delimiters.  Try escaping them.

Comment: @ghoti: Or just use an alternate delimiter such as `|` in the `sed` command.

Comment: Even escaping the slashes seems to hang me up on char 15.  Which I assume means char 15 of $line_old which is a single quote.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - I was under the impression that the alternate delimiter only worked as a delimiter for sed's substitution (`s`) command, and couldn't be used as the boundary of of a 1addr regex.  Indeed, with a 1addr of `121`, how would sed know if you wanted to execute a command on line 121, or on every line containing a "2"?  Note that the OP is using a `c` (delete pattern space) command, not a `s` (substitute).

Comment: @ghoti: You'd use `\121` to use "1" as a delimiter for a 1addr. Similarly, `\|pattern|` to use a pipe.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Wow.  I had no idea.  Thanks again!  :)

Comment: What is you sed's version, GNU, BSD ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the trouble is `//` in `$line_old` and `$line_new`.
It causes problem with `sed` delimiters

I wish I had your file for work on it, but I can give you the way :
You can use `sed` with different delimiters, for example :

```
$ echo 'foo' | sed s#foo#bar#
bar
```

More [here](http://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/).

Comment: The square brackets and other regex specials in the regex have to be backslash-escaped as well. It's doable in shell / sed but I would move to Perl at this point.

Comment: Zulu Here you go!:
`
redisconfig ()
{
CMD="ssh -q -t -i $HOME/.ssh/amazon-key.pem ubuntu@128.59.120.21"
line_old="ENV['REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://redis:X9g55eUPmq01yY4@ip-10-225-52-138.us-west-2.compute.internal:6379'"
line_new="ENV['REDIS_URL'] = 'redis://redis:X9g55eUPmq01yY4@$2:6379'"

echo $line_old
echo $line_new

updateconfig="$($CMD sed -i "|$line_old|$line_new|" /home/ubuntu/config/testing.rb)"
results="$($CMD grep 'REDIS_URL' /home/ubuntu/config/testing.rb)"
echo $updateconfig
echo $results
}

$1
`
You can simply create the testing file and put the line we are searching for in it.